# ionic doesn't install app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to simulate my app on ios simulator with ionic. But when I run:

```
ionic build ios
ionic emulate ios
```

My app doesn't appear on the simulator. What should I do?

Comment: Did the simulator does not launch app or did it launch with `ionic emulate ios` but your app is not installed on it and doesn't launch ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install IOS-Sim tool.
**The ios-sim tool** is a command-line utility that launches an iOS application on the iOS Simulator.

Apply this command on terminal window:

```
$ sudo npm install ios-sim -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added the iOS platform to the project and verify that you have the iOS-Sim tool. If this is the problem you should a message that you are missing any of those two in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using visual studio, you need to configure the remote ios agent. 
follow this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn757054.aspx#ios to configure and test you application

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, an ionic app can take a really long time to load on the simulator. First try waiting.

Second, if it still doesn't load, know that the simulator is a lot pickier about what it will run and not run than the browser. Check if you app works in the browser. Try a different browser (such as Firefox). If it does not, debug from there. If it does work in the browser, run your code through a linter to find that one semi-colon that your browser didn't care about.

Answer (score 0):

Try start do it on xcode(in each my ionic/cordova project i have to use some native solutions to build application for iOS i use xcode for android i use android studio)

I know that different platform need some hours of adapt but this knowledge is very important

Answer (score 0):

Try remove and add platform again.

```
ionic platform rm ios
```

and

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use following commands to build and run your ionic app respectively.

```
ionic cordova build ios 
ionic cordova run ios
```